# Javascript Modifying object property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
var objA = {
    title: "",
    subtitle: ""
};

var objB = {
    properties: {
        title: "",
        subtitle: ""
    }
};

objB.properties.title = objA.title;
```

I have been using the above code line to map properties from one object to    another.My object structure needs to be changed to the following below:-

var lang = "en";

```
objB = {
    properties: {
        title: {
            en: ""
        },
        subtitle: {
            en: ""
        }
    }
};
```

What should be the code syntax to make corresponding change ?
Sorry if question seems silly,  I am new to JS.

Comment: so what is stopping you from doing that??

Answer (score 1):

You must have a read: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Like all JavaScript variables, both the object name (which could be a normal variable) and property name are case sensitive. You can define/change a property by assigning it a value:

```js
var a = { 
  hello : "hi", 
  name : "Rohan" 
};

a.name = {
  en: a.name
};

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Can you please take another look at question ? I have modified it slightly.

Comment: With the change on the object `objB` the syntax should be: `objB.properties.title.en = objA.title;`

Comment: You're just assigning `objA.title` value to the object property `objB.properties.title.en`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = { hello : "hi", name : "Rohan" };

a.name = {en: a.name};
//or
a["name"] = {"en": a["name"]}
```

Comment: Better to access object properties in dot notation: `a.name`

Comment: Thats true, but example added to work if the key has space or any other invalid characters `a = {"first-name":"Rohan"}` `a = {"first name":"Rohan"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {'hello': 'hi'};

a.name = {
    'en': 'Rohan'
};
```

What's the problem?